# How to insert pdf file or word into OrientDB with OrientDBStudio?

Tags: binary, orientdb

Im trying to create a new record that contains a pdf in one of the properties but when i click the save button this error message appears:

```
"com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Error on       unmarshalling JSON content for record: \"@class\":\"Documento\",\"@version\":0,\"@rid\":\"#-1:-1\",\"Nombre\":\"Exam\",\"Materia\":\"#12:0\",\"Tipo\":\"Exam\",\"Formato\":\"Pdf\",\"Archivo\":\"$file\",\"Tamano\":2\r\n--> com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Bad Base64 input character decimal 36 in array position 0"
```

The question is: Is it possible to save a pdf document in OrientDB? How do i solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now there is a problem with multipart upload, and even if this problem will be fixed,
if you use studio to upload file, you will have a bunch of binary data with no sense for studio that doesn't know how to handle that data (without mime-type).OrientDB doesn't have the concept of attachments like Couchdb does, you have to create your own Document if you want to handle file and use Document Api.